# Add more adio-related tags

Tags: feature-request

I just realized that there are not that many audio-related tags.

What about tags like these:?

- SFX (general) sound effects
- spatial-audio (rather generic)
- dolby-atmos (rather specific)
- audio-5.1 (for 5.1), audio-7.1 (obvious, hopefully), etc. maybe stereo (audio-2.0), too.

Answer (score 1):

The process for tags is that they are created when it is obvious we have a need for them, so at this stage we just don't have the demand for those tags. There are no questions which require them.

We do not want to create tags pre-emptively, hoping that they will then be used by questions that come along later.

If you have a few good questions each of these topics, please do post them and once we have enough questions to warrant the new tags, we can create them.

Comment: https://video.stackexchange.com/q/36067/33658